# React SPA - Show loading screen until multiple components are rendered

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, webpack, react-router

Apologies for the relatively conceptual question. I'm attempting to emulate the full-page *Heroku* loading screen that appears when the page first loads and disappears after the navbar, images, libraries, and other components have mounted:

[image: Heroku loading screenshot]

I know the underlying stack of Heroku is *Ember*, but is there a good practice/way for accomplishing a similar effect using *node.js*, *webpack*, *react*, *react-router*, and *express*. It's not isomorphic and I would prefer all rendering to take place on the client.

Thank you for your help and let me know if there's any other information that would be helpful in understanding what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this but I imagine you could simply provide the HTML for your 'full page loading screen' as the initial HTML that comes with your page, and then simply replace it with your ReactDOM.render call which will only get processed after everything has been processed.

More specifically, if you put all of your JS script tags in the footer, then the rest of your document will load and render while the scripts are being loaded, giving you your 'loading screen' effect. It should work to simply put the loading graphic within a div and then render over it with React.

Comment: Silly me, of course, this makes the most sense. Thank you v. much! I placed a tiny CSS spinner in the HTML and then loaded all of the react scripts generated by webpack afterwards.

Comment: Actually one more thing I've run into is that safari, for some reason, does not render the page content even if the scripts are placed at the bottom of the body. It shows the address bar progress indicator and doesn't actually show the page until everything has loaded, making the progress loading html useless. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Oh, perhaps try to add `async` to your script tag to see if it allows the page to render. Otherwise try to look for other ways to ensure your script is loaded asynchronously, perhaps like this one: https://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/